# Python module execution not being procedural

Tags: python, linux, replit

I am making a python module to edit a BrainFuck script and make it easy to program. (This is just for fun.) I have run into a problem where the functions are executing out of order and I have no idea how to fix it.

__init__.py:

```
#main
def init():
  f=open("main.bf","w")
  f.close
  f=open("BrainF/cell.txt","w")
  f.write("0")
  f.close

class cell:
  def goto(num):
    f=open("BrainF/cell.txt","r")
    current_cell=int(f.read())
    f.close
    y=current_cell-num
    if num >> current_cell:
      f=open("main.bf","a")
      x="a"*(num-current_cell)
      for i in x:
        f.write(">")
      f.close()
    if num << current_cell:
      f=open("main.bf","a")
      x="a"*abs(y)
      for i in x:
        f.write("<")
      f.close()
      
    f=open("BrainF/cell.txt","w")
    f.write(str(num))
    f.close
    
  def add(num):
    f=open("main.bf","a")
    x="a"*num
    for i in x:
      f.write("+")
    f.close()
    
  def subtract(num):
    f=open("main.bf","a")
    x="a"*num
    for i in x:
      f.write("-")
    f.close()
```

main.py:

```
import BrainF as bf

bf.init()
bf.cell.goto(2)
bf.cell.add(3)
bf.cell.goto(0)
```

file tree:

```
main.bf
main.py
BrainF
--__pycache__
--__init__.py
--cell.txt
```

When I run main.py with the command, `python main.py` it writes to main.bf. The problem is that it should execute in the correct order and main.bf would be `>>+++<<` but instead, it does not and the actual contents is `>><<+++`.

Is there any way to fix this so that the functions execute in order?

Link to repl to try for yourself:
https://replit.com/@SamuelAndrews-Pirona/Python-BrainF

Comment: `f.close` is the method object whereas `f.close()` **calls** the `close` method of the `f` object

Comment: @JacquesGaudin yes, I use f.close() to update the file and I just re-open it when needed.

Comment: You are trying to use it but you forgot the brackets in 3 locations.

Comment: What are you expecting `if num >> current_cell:` to do?  That's a bit shift, not a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The problem was me not returning after finishing the function, and using >> instead of >. I fixed it and it works on the repl as well.

If you want, you can check in on the repl and use it as a easy python to BrainFuck translator!